# What does this error mean and how do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, create-react-app

After trying to create a react app with the command `npx create-react-app myApp`, this error message popped up. What does it mean?

OSX: 10.15.6
node version 10.13.0
npm version 6.14.4

````
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../lib/utils/unsupported.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:19:21
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:153:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)```
````

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you are trying to run a module `unsupported.js` from a folder that doesn't contain it, to solve this look in the folder pallet locate the `unsupported.js` file and then check the root folder where this file is located, and access the folder from terminal or  locate the folder in your computer and then open the folder from your IDE so that you will be able to access the files in the folder